# angular 15 build process

Tags: mediaelement, angular15

I have `angular 6` application and we use `mediaelement 4.2.9` as part of the video display wherein if we do `ng build --configuration=local/production --watch` the .svg files for controls were not created separately however they were part of the .js file only

Now if we follow the same process in `angular 15.2.4,` the .svg files are created separately. and when we deploy the files icons are not rendered on the production environment.

My question is there any change in terms of the build process in angular now ? or I am missing something here?